# Python logging, not getting any output

Tags: python

I am sorry to ask, as it is not the first time, but I have not been able to fix it my self by looking at older posts.

Im trying to create and write to a logfile using python. I am creating the file just fine, but there is no input to the file that I am making.

here is my code:

```
import logging

log_file = '/home/user/Test.log'

form = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG , format=form)

logging.debug = ('DEBUG MESSAGE!')
```

Comment: Did you try changing your logging level to a more higher priority one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to change:

`logging.debug = ('DEBUG MESSAGE!')`

to

`logging.debug('DEBUG MESSAGE!')`

This way it should work!

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: @LasseBøg Welcome!